# Link mcv User identity to my model classes in different project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP MVC 5 application with the following projects

1. MyApp.Web ==> controls views, js, ...Etc
2. MyApp.Models ==> Entities
3. MyApp.Dao ==> contain EF DB contexts, configuration ... etc

In my `MyApp.Models` project i have the following classes

1. Review
2. Item
3. AppUser

I want to store user information in the table AppUser also (store/link) his login ... etc
i want to be able to link some items to AppUser who should be able to login.

In other words, using the code generated by a new mcv application, how can i assign items to users

can i do that with the default implementation code generated by a new ASP.NET mcv project or do i have to rework every thing? i will use EF and SQL server
I red tones of posts followed some tutorials for how to implement ASP.NET identity with no success.

Samples code will highly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Development blog has an example of how to extend the the ASPNET Identity user model here: [Customizing profile information in ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) that should help you out.